# How can draw line by points from database on Telerik RadMap?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, telerik

I need to show route between point that stored in the sql server database and find these threads
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/map-client-side-data-binding.html
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/map/examples/functionality/cross-layer-integration/defaultcs.aspx

My problem is that in these examples rout point are in json file.
Please help me to bind shapelayer to database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks rdmptn for your answer.
Yes you are right, thers is not simple way to do that.
I started a thread in telerik forum and received a way to do that. it's not simple But it can be done.

the main thread is :
http://www.telerik.com/forums/display-linestring-%28route%29-from-database-on-the-map#0LHAMeP5PE2NarOrcBfytQ

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.

Those examples show how to bind a shapes layer to a data source. Client-side data source is the only supported type at the moment.

Thus, you can consider creating the json files with server code depending on the information in the database. Or, use pure client-side binding and create a webservice that will return the geoJSON objects. In any case, that's not an easy task. If you manage to do that, create a code library, I think a lot of people will be grateful: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/aspnet-ajax/map